# Frequency of Heavenly judgment

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, reward-punishment, heaven

@Maurice has asked a series of interesting questions on how our reward and punishment system works. We generally hold that Yom Kippur is the time of the final verdict for a year, but I'd like to know how it works in details throughout the year:

1. Does the Y"K verdict cover *everything* that will happen in the following year second by second - when one will be punished or rewarded? Say: "*on Nov. 22 you'll get a big bonus, but on Dec. 12 you'll catch the flu.*"
2. If the judgment is ongoing, how frequently it is held - weekly, daily, hourly?
3. (maybe a standalone Q.) What is the minimal and maximal delay between the judgment and its execution?

Comment: Maximal delay between the judgment and its execution would be until the end of the year, because then its Judgement Day again

Comment: According to those that hold it's daily or hourly, what is the significance of the judgement on Rosh Hashanah then?

Answer (score 1):

A *beraita* quoted on [Rosh HaShanah 16a](https://www.sefaria.org/Rosh_Hashanah.16a.6?lang=bi):

> הכל נידונים בר"ה וגזר דין שלהם נחתם ביוה"כ דברי ר"מ ר' יהודה אומר הכל נידונין בר"ה וגזר דין שלהם נחתם כל אחד ואחד בזמנו בפסח על התבואה בעצרת על פירות האילן בחג נידונין על המים ואדם נידון בר"ה וגזר דין שלו נחתם ביוה"כ ר' יוסי אומר אדם נידון בכל יום שנאמר (איוב ז, יח) ותפקדנו לבקרים רבי נתן אומר אדם נידון בכל שעה שנא' (איוב ז, יח) לרגעים תבחננו‏
>
> All are judged on Rosh HaShana, and their sentence is sealed on Yom Kippur; this is the statement of Rabbi Meir. Rabbi Yehuda says: All are judged on Rosh HaShana, and their sentence is sealed each in its own time: On Passover the sentence is sealed concerning grain; on Shavuot concerning fruits that grow on a tree; on the festival of Sukkot they are judged concerning water; and mankind is judged on Rosh HaShana, and the sentence is sealed on Yom Kippur. Rabbi Yosei says: A person is judged every day, and not just once a year, as it is stated: “You visit him every morning” (Job 7:18), meaning that every morning an accounting is made and a judgment is passed. Rabbi Natan says: A person is judged every hour, as it is stated: “You try him every moment” (Job 7:18).

Comment: Thank you, How do we Paskinan? Rambam? Are all three accepted?